# Is const char* pointing to a single character or a string?

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, char

I got this simple question as to how can I declare a char pointer pointing to single character.

Is it that `char*` can point to a single character and also to a string. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Some people get confused because standard functions like strlen get a pointer and do not know the length of the string. Well, these functions scan for '\0'. Basically they just start with a memory address no matter if it is a character or a long string!

Answer (score 4):

In C there is no data type `string`.

C-"string"s are simple `char`-arrays with an array-element carrying the value of `'\0'` (the `0`-terminator) to mark the end of the "string".

A `char*` **always** referrs to a `char`, whether there are more `char`s "following" is not obvious from the `char`-pointer itself, but only from the way the pointer was set.

```
char c1 = 'A';
char * p1 = &c1; /* p1 points to exctly one char. */
char * p2 = malloc(42); /* If malloc did not fail p2 points to 42 chars, else p2 would be NULL. */
char str1[4] = "alk";
char * p3 = str1; /* p3 points to 3 + 1 = 4 chars (3 for the chars 'a', 'l', 'k' and 1 for the trailing 0-terminator. */
```

Comment: I think you mean `char const * str1 = "alk";` or `char str1[] = "alk";`

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks for notifing. Fixed.  @user694733

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can point to a single character. It can also point to a string. It depends on how you use it.

For example:

```
char str[] = "ABCDEFG";
const char *a = str + 2;
```

Here we can say both "`a` points to a single character 'C'" and "`a` points to a string 'CDEFG'".

`printf("%c", *a);` prints "C", while `printf("%s", a);` prints "CDEFG".

Comment: In fact, a `char*` *does* point to a single `char`.  That some functions & algorithms happen to scan past that char looking for something else is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them. It points to a part of memory, it can has just one element or more. Depends on your usage.

```
char *x = (char*) malloc(1 ); // Just one

char *x = (char*) malloc(10); // A sequence of characters (string)
```

In fact a pointer contains an address, C or C++ make you free to how do you use it. If you use it by `*x` you are deferencing it as a single character, and `x` itself can be defined as the first character of a string (until `\0` in C-style strings)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. A pointer only consists of the address of some data, there is no "target element count" associated with the pointer.

This is not specific to `char *` (character/string) pointers, it's true for all pointers.

Whenever you have a pointer, you can use it the basis for indexing, as if the pointer pointed at an array.

Answer (score 0):

It points on some memory adress. It can be one element of char, or first element in array - this array is string. So index will be just offset from this first element.

Answer (score 0):

A string is only a sequence of characters terminated by the `\0` character. 
A pointer only holds the address of a variable; it can be anything.

Even if you assign your char* to a sting, if you get it's value you will still only get one character(but if you use it with a string manipulation method you will operate on the whole string as those functions look for the `\0` termination.

Answer (score 0):

Any pointer points to **one object**. The type of the object that refered to by the pointer is specified in the pointer declaration.

So for example

```
const char *p = "ABCD";
```

points to **one object** (not objects) of type char. That is it points to the first character of string literal "ABCD". Take into account that the type of the string literal itself is `const char[5]` that is it is an array and not one character. Simply in this case the character pointed to by the pointer is a part of the string literal. So you may use it (for example by means of incrementing) to access other characters of the literal.

Also I would append the post with pointers to functions.

There is a good relevant quote in the C Standard

> A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type,
>   called the referenced type. A pointer type describes **an object**
>   whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type.
>   A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called
>   ‘‘pointer to T’’.